# How to display formatted text in Layout Preview as tools:text?

Tags: android

Here is content of `Strings.xml`:

```
<string name="player_x_score">Player \u2014 %1$s</string>
```

Here is content of `Layout.xml`:

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_x_score"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            tools:background="@drawable/selected_score_border"
            tools:text="@string/player_x_score"
            tools:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

In Android Studio Layout Preview, the view is displayed as below (**which is correct**):

[image]

Question: **How to make the Layout Preview to display with sample text as "Player - 0" while using tools:text as below?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `example` values in your string resources file via an `xliff` tag on the resource entry:

```
<string name="player_x_score">Player \u2014 <xliff:g name="player_name" example="0">%1$s</xliff:g></string>
```

This will allow that string to show as `Player - 0` in the layout preview.

Also, if the player value will always be a number, consider switching to `%1$d` instead.